# Use MVC with SDL makes sense?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, sdl

I was wondering is it makes sense in real world programming to use the Model View Controller design pattern in a SDL based game?

I mean, what are the pros and cons for it?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2210098/1316620

Answer (score 0):

As for MVC is encapsulation.

Let's say you create a RPG game, you will want to separate the display fully from the game logic. When you change your mind about the camera movement, you will only change the view, leaving the model and controller alone.